# float: left; ambiguity - CSS

Tags: html, css

Lets take two images as an example

**With** `float: left;`

[image]

**Without** `float: left;`

[image]

**HTML**

```
<h6><span>Sign Up</span></h6>
```

**CSS**

```
h6:before {
   content: url("images/arrow.png");
   padding-right: 8px;
   float: left; // Here lies problem
}
```

**Question**

Why **without** `float: left;` text (Signup) goes down ? What's science behind this ?

Comment: I think it´s because you need to set `vertical-align`.. On float by default is already setting ´vertical-align´

Comment: Yeah, the default would be `baseline` for the vertical alignment...`middle` would be better.

Comment: Without the rest of the css rules, it's difficult to pin down the real reason. Is  arrow.png's height taller than the span?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default display mode of a pseudo element is `display: inline;` and the default vertical alignment is `vertical-align: baseline;`. This means that the image will be aligned to the baseline of the text.

When you `float` an element its display mode becomes `display: block;` and it is removed from the document flow. Vertical alignment is no longer a factor and in this case the top edge of the `span` is now aligned with the top edge of the floated pseudo element.

As Luis P. A. and Paulie_D allude to in the comments, changing the vertical alignment will allow for the non-floated pseudo element to be aligned to the middle of the text:

```css
h6:before {
  content: url("http://placehold.it/20x20");
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
h6 span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h6><span>Sign Up</span></h6>
```

Comment: same goes for `float: right;` ?? ... what about `float: none;` ??

Comment: @Junaid Yup the same applies for `float: right;`. `float: none;` will not take the element out of the document flow, nor change it to `display: block;` so it will still act as an `inline` element.